# How to handle SSL certs in a multi-master OpenLDAP setup?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, openldap

I have two servers working in a multi-master mirror mode OpenLDAP setup.

server-0.example.com, server-1.example.com and server-vip.example.com

server-vip.example.com is a floating virtual IP that associates itself on the interface of the active node (server-0 or server-1), a rather common setup.

the problem is, I created some self signed certificates with a CA on server-0. what is the distribution of ssl client/server certificates that needs to happen for the two servers to speak to each other, and more importantly, for clients to speak to server-vip.example.com?

simply copy/pasting configs doesn't seem to be the answer, especially since the common name on the servers is unique, they each have different host names.

also, if server-0 goes down, and server-vip points at server-1, how are clients supposed to transparently work in as far as SSL goes if they have a client certificate for server-0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a single certificate with multiple subjectAltNames that will be valid for all hostnames listed. Personally, rather than use self-signed certs I prefer to run a private CA using the OpenVPN [easy-rsa](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/miscellaneous/77-rsa-key-management.html) scripts, for which there's a [patch for subjectAltName support](http://www.bisente.com/proyectos/easy-rsa-subjectaltname/).

Comment: This is a reasonable solution, but be aware that this requires your clients / SSL libraries to understand subjectAltName.  "Try it and see" :-)

Answer (score 0):

you should create three certificates:

- one for server-0
- one for server-1
- one for server-vip

give the server-vip certificate to your clients as trusted certificate. server-0 must have the certificate of server-1 as trusted and vice versa.

this way your clients won't recognize a failover and your servers are independent of the server-vip certificate.